# How to compile JRTPLIB for ios

Tags: ios

I built a project for sending or receiving audio data and tended to use RTP protocol. So I'm trying to compile JRTPLIB which I have downloaded from the web,it is written by C++,but I have no idea.I am new for these.

Does anyone know how to compile JRTPLIB which is able to use on ios? I would be very grateful if given the detailed steps.